# Печать через USB из термо-принтера Java

Tags: java, печать

Хочу печатать чеки из термо-принтера VKP80II с Java через USB. Долго насиловал гугл, на русском ничего не нашел. На анг форумах нашел способ через ком порт. Но мне нужен печать именно с USB. Как я понял (немного с анг форумов) для USB тоже требуется jPOS. 
Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой и смог решить, или те кто шарит в теме прощу помощи. 
Советами, указаниями или если есть кусками кода.
Благодарю за обращенное внимание.

Comment: Вероятно подключение через USB добавляет виртуальный COM порт в систему, с которым и нужно работать.

Comment: Нет, для кома драйвер не требуется, с ним можно напрямую работать без USB (так говориться на некоторых форумах). А чтобы работать с USB нужен драйвер или можно работать с некоторыми, не известными мне библиотеками?

Comment: Подключите устройство и посмотрите в диспетчере устройств (или в /dev для linux) появился ли COM порт дополнительный в системе. Как правило, если принтер имеет вариации с USB и COM интерфейсами, то USB вариант через стандартные драйвера системы опознается как COM порт.

Comment: Есть мнение, что в виндовсе с usb устройством можно работать только через драйвер. Виртуальный com-порт это тот же драйвер. Для устройств, поддерживающих USB communication devices class даже используется встроенный в ос драйвер (не требуется установка дополнительного софта). Зачем возится с драйвером какого-то другого типа, если есть хорошо изученный com-порт?

Comment: Вы можете найти на сайте производителя или в интернете драйвера для ос и драйвера для javapos. Очевидно понадобится и сам javapos http://www.javapos.com/index.html